# Going Up Theorem and Affine Sets.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

So for an affine scheme, we know that this is true: Suppose that $k$ was algebraically closed.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be affine schemes and $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a polynomial map with the corresponding coordinate ring homomorphism $\Phi: Spec(Y) \rightarrow Spec(X)$. I can show that $\Phi$ is going up, then $\phi$ is a closed map. (Follows from the going up theorem and surjectivity is given so that forces $\phi$ to be closed and vice versa)

But if what if $X$ and $Y$ were affine sets(So $X$ and $Y$ could be reducible) instead? If we have a polynomial map $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ and the corresponding coordinate ring $\Phi: k[Y] \rightarrow k[X]$. Does $\Phi$ going up imply that $\phi$ is closed and vice versa?

This required a bit of thought for me. I thought it would be exactly the same for an affine scheme, but the inclusion map is going up does not imply we have surjectivity. So I'm not exactly sure if this is true or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of finite type of noetherian schemes. Then $f(X)$ is a constructible subset of $Y$. If $f$ is going-up, that is, if $f(X)$ is closed under specialization, then $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$. This is stated in Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, II, ex. 3.18c, ex 3.19.

Now if $X,Y$ are affine algebraic schemes over a field $k$ then $X$ and $Y$ are obviously noetherian. Furthermore $f$ is of finite type, as the morphisms $X \to k$ and $Y \to k$ are of finite type and $Y \to k$ is separated. (Hartshorne ex. II, 4.8d).

Comment: I'm not sure if you read the question. My question was if $X$ and $Y$ were just affine algebraic sets (so we can have that $X$ and $Y$ are reducible in the Zariski topology). Does the question I have still hold?

Comment: Let $X$ be an "affine algebraic set" in your terminology. Then I understood it as meaning $X={\mathrm spec}(A)$ where $A=B/I$ and $B=k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is a polynomial ring over $k$ and $I \subseteq B$ an arbitrary ideal. This is exactly what I called "affine algebraic scheme" in my answer.